# Draw full screen quad in vertex shader

Tags: shader, metal

I came across this sample code from Apple Metal documentation. How does this vertex shader draw a full screen quad using 3 vertices ?

```
// Draw command after setting pipeline state    
renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 3)

typedef struct {
float4 position [[position]];
half3  worldNormal;
} ColorInOut;

/// A vertex function that generates full screen quad pass.
vertex ColorInOut quadPassVertex(uint vid[[vertex_id]])
{
    ColorInOut out;
    
    float4 position;
    position.x = (vid == 2) ? 3.0 : -1.0;
    position.y = (vid == 0) ? -3.0 : 1.0;
    position.zw = 1.0;
    
    out.position = position;
    
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The triangle that's drawn covers the whole normalized device coordinates [-1, 1] in both x and y directions. The extra area of the triangle that's outside the [-1, 1] bounds gets clipped in later stages of the pipeline.